# change eth0 to eth1 without udev

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I have a very interesting issue. We have Redhat 4 Linux and it is has **4** ethernet interfaces:

```
eth0
eth1
eth2
eth3
```

Now, only `eth0` is connected to LAN and everything is working fine. We have special software which needs `eth2` and won't work without the `eth2` interface. I therefore want to convert `eth0` to `eth2`.

I don't have a `70-persistent-networking.rules` file in udev. It looks like we have a very old version of `udev` running and it doesn't use that file.

/etc/modprobe.conf:

```
alias eth0 bnx2
alias eth1 bnx2
alias eth2 bnx2
alias eth3 bnx2
```

I have tried to swap `MAC` address in `ifcfg-eth` files but still not working.

**Note:** we can't swap the cables because this server is a blade server inside a chassis, and the server is located in a remote datacenter.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you may be able to create two devices reserving the names `eth0` and `eth1` before loading the actual network driver which then should use `eth2`. There's a kernel module named `dummy` with which you should be able to accomplish this:

```
modprobe dummy numdummies=2
ip l set dev dummy0 name eth0
ip l set dev dummy1 name eth1
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have 70-persistent-networking.rules file in udev, look like we have very old version of udev running and it doesn't use that file.

I'm no expert on the evolution of `udev`, but if there's somewhere you're not finding that file (`/etc/udev/rules.d`), then you can create it.  `udev` just processes files in that directory in lexicographical order -- that's why they use names beginning with numbers.  However, it should still read and apply *every* `.rules` file there.  Might as well save yours for last, so put whatever you want into `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-my.rules`.